# what is the meaning of filching in the context of logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Going over `logging` module and saw this:

```
# next bit filched from 1.5.2's inspect.py
def currentframe():
    """Return the frame object for the caller's stack frame."""
    try:
        raise Exception
    except:
        return sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back

if hasattr(sys, '_getframe'): currentframe = lambda: sys._getframe(3)
# done filching
```

What is the meaning of the phrase "filching" in this context?

Comment: “Stolen” “taken” - in this context: “copied”

Comment: My guess is the exception is thrown _specifically_ so the backtrace frame can be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [barny commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902613/what-is-the-meaning-of-filching-in-the-context-of-logging-module#comment94650184_53902613), the *comment* that reads:

```
# next bit filched from 1.5.2's inspect.py
```

uses the word to mean "copied from".  That is, this particular code sequence has been around for a very long time, since Python version 1.5.2.

What's *going on* here (edit: this part of the question got edited away!) is simple yet subtle.  Any exception causes the Python system to locate the innermost, currently-active `except` handler.  In this case, that's the very next line—so:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except:
    ...
```

proceeds directly to the `...` line.  However, the `raise` has a *side effect*, which is the key to the whole thing.  The side effect is that the `raise` makes the *traceback stack* contain, as the most recent entry,<sup>1</sup> the execution state pointing to the `raise` line itself.

The `sys.exc_info()` function returns a tuple with three elements: the exception's type, the exception's value—no value was passed here because the handler doesn't need one—and the (entire) traceback stack.  The `[2]` extracts this traceback stack from the tuple, discarding the exception type and value.

The structure of the traceback stack is somewhat complicated, but there is a `.tb_frame` attribute in each traceback stack instance.  This contains information about stack frame that was active when the exception occurred.  Since this is a stack of function activations, its predecessor is the state that was active at the call to `currentframe`, so this is the caller's frame.

This method of locating the caller's frame is not very efficient (and, as [holdenweb points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902686/1256452), specific to the CPython interpreter), so if `sys` has a `_getframe` function, the file re-binds `currentframe` to invoke `sys._getframe(3)`.  (I'm not sure what the constant 3 is doing here since the other version effectively returns what `sys._getframe(0)` would return.  Edit 2: on further inspection, the magic constant 3 takes care of the log handler calling `_log` which calls `findCaller` which calls `currentframe`.  This is another efficiency hack since `findCaller` climbs up through each stack frame looking for one that occurs in some file *other than* the logging module code itself.  This starts it at a better point.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember, a stack is any data structure that behaves in a last-in first-out (LIFO) fashion.  The Python interpreter manages a bunch of different, but more or less simultaneous, stacks, including the exception handlers and the normal function-call mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

This is code you don't want to take as a good example! First of all it's specific to the CPython implementation, and so won't work under PyPy, Jython, Iron Python and so on.

I presume the author raises the exception in order to access the stack frame of the calling routine, or perhaps it's caller's caller.

"Filching" is taking without permission, so this is just a guilt-ridden way of saying "I copied and pasted from an open source library."